# Convergence in Probability with known expectation and variance limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Very noob at this, and it seems not to be a difficult exercise:

If $E[X_n] \xrightarrow{ n \to \infty } \alpha$ and $Var(X_n) \xrightarrow{ n \to \infty } 0$

Then $X_n \xrightarrow{ n \to \infty } \alpha$ in Probability

Comment: One way to do that is Chebyshev inequility.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. 
Pick $N$ large enough so that $| E[X_n] - \alpha| < \epsilon/2$ for all $n \ge N$.

Note that for a fixed $n$, $\{ |X_n - \alpha| \ge \epsilon\} \subset  \{ |X_n - E[X_n]| \ge \epsilon/2 \} \cup \{ | E[X_n] - \alpha| \ge \epsilon/2 \}$. (For if $|X_n - E[X_n|] < \epsilon/2$ and $|E[X_n] - \alpha| < \epsilon/2$, then by the triangle inequality we'd have $|X_n - \alpha| < \epsilon$.)

Then specifically for all $n \ge N$, we have $\{ |X_n - \alpha| \ge \epsilon\} \subset  \{ |X_n - E[X_n]| \ge \epsilon/2 \}$.

Since probability is montone with respect to set containment, for all $n \ge N$ we have
\begin{align*}
P( |X_n - \alpha| \ge \epsilon) &\le P( |X_n - E[X_n]| \ge \epsilon/2) \\
&\le \dfrac{4 \text{Var}X_n}{\epsilon^2} 
\end{align*}

where the last inequality comes from Chebyshev. Taking $n \to \infty$ gives the desired result.